# Issue to get total amount while using inner join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I get an wrong TotalPrice from the ItemDetails table while join the taxdetails table.

Code 1:
   `select Distinct B.ID as BillId, 
                    I.ID as ItemDetailId, 
                    I.TotalPrice as ItemPrice, 
                    T.Amount as TaxAmount from Bill B
    inner join ItemDetails I on I.BillNoID = B.ID
    inner join TaxDetails T on T.ItemDetailId = I.Id;`

Refer below image,
[image]

While sum the TotalPrice and TotalTaxAmount on the same query i got an wrong TotalPrice result,

Code 2:
   `select Distinct B.ID as BillId, 
           SUM(I.TotalPrice) as TotalPrice, 
           SUM(T.Amount) as TotalTaxAmount from Bill B
    inner join ItemDetails I on I.BillNoID = B.ID
    inner join TaxDetails T on T.ItemDetailId = I.Id
    group by B.ID;`

Please refer below image,
[image]

Actual issue is as per taxdetails per itemdetail each row the rows become multiple so the totalprice get differs.

Expected Output for code 2 (i have listed the first row expected result) is, 
Billid TotalPrice  TotalTaxAmount 
  1          70          30

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MySQL? You tagged them both.

Comment: use group by b.id only and then use sum, remove distinct b.id

Comment: @Patrick Hofman I have used MYSQL.

Comment: @Viswanathpolaki same issue occurs after removed distinct b.id

Answer (score 2):

Try this,you have multiple items/bill, that is why you can't make inner join directly.Remove group by also.

```
 select B.ID as BillId, 
           I.TotalPrice as TotalPrice, 
           T.Amount as TotalTaxAmount from Bill B
    inner join 
        (
            select BillNoID,SUM(TotalPrice) as TotalPrice from ItemDetails
            group by BillNoID
        )as I on I.BillNoID = B.ID
    inner join 
        (
            Select ItemDetailId,SUM(Amount) as Amount from TaxDetails
            group by ItemDetailId
        )as T on T.ItemDetailId = I.Id
```

Comment: your answer is helpful for me but, there is any other way to solve this issue without using sub-query?

Comment: You can try cross apply